# jQuery Uploadify Not Handling Large Images

Tags: php, jquery, upload

I am using jQuery Uploadify plug-in. It works great for what I'm doing, but when I recently tested it with images over 2.5mb, it fails.

The process completes, states that the file is 100% uplaoded, but the file never arrives in the uploaded folder.
The log files say that the script can't find the file.

I checked the PHP.ini file settings, the log files and everything else I could think of (firebug, etc). However, this is not coming up with real results.

Any help? Ideas?

**Update:** The PHP settings in .ini were updated, but PHP info shows:

```
max_execution_time  30  30
max_file_uploads    20  20
max_input_nesting_level 64  64
max_input_time  60  60
memory_limit    32M 32M
```

An image takes well over 30 seconds to upload, could this be the problem?

Comment: What are the PHP.ini settings saying?

Comment: Updated the question to show the stats from PHP Info

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about PHP's [upload_max_filesize](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.upload-max-filesize)? And Apache's (assuming that's what you're running) [LimitRequestBody](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#limitrequestbody)?

Comment: Yeah, but 2.5 MB? Sounds really odd... I agree they are still worth checking out though, if just to make sure.

Answer (score 2):

The only thing that comes to mind is that if you are resizing the image on server side, the script could die because it takes up more than the 32MB of memory you have available.

Remember, resizing takes at least

```
width x height x 3 (or 4)
```

bytes of memory - it's meaningless how small the compressed JPEG image is.

Comment: That's what I thought too, but there are two operations: First, it uploads the file to /uploads/, Secondly it sends it to an image resizing script. It never arrives in /uploads/.

Comment: @gamerz maybe write into a log file or send a debug E-Mail just to see whether the script gets called at all? (Probably not) Also, what does your callback on JS side look like? Are you catching error codes and stuff?... I'm off now for the night, good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Try explicitly setting a `sizelimit`:

```
 $("#fileInput3").uploadify({
    'uploader'       : '/_scripts/uploadify.swf',
    'script'         : '/_scripts/uploadify.php',
    'cancelImg'      : '/_images/cancel.png',
    'folder'         : '/_uploads',
    'auto'           : true,
    'sizeLimit'      : 10000000
    'multi'          : false
});
```

Ref : http://www.uploadify.com/documentation/

Comment: Tried this beforehand. It is currently set to 20mb, but I had it at 200mb and same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try uploading anything other than images to check?

Also, are you sure that you pointing to the right upload destination? Correct permissions?

Comment: I have uploaded smaller images successfully, but I will test a larger PDF file or similiar right now.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and this was quite easy to figure out from php.log what is going on:

```
PHP Warning:  POST Content-Length of 13811706 bytes exceeds the limit of 8388608 bytes in Unknown on line 0
```

In php.ini is to set "post_max_size" to value you want, eg. 20M